calculating gradient of a function
I have $2$ point $x, y$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$ and I have to find the grandient respect to $y$ of the following function $f(x,y) =\frac{1}{|x-y|}$. I know the results should be $\frac{x-y}{|x-y|^3}$ One method I tried is writing the function as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|^2 + |y|^2 - 2|x||y|cos \theta}} $. Now my function depends on $|y|$ and $\theta$, so the gradient respect to $y$ is gradient in polar coordinate respect to $|y|$ and $\theta$. Using the formula for gradient in polar coordinate I get $\frac{(|x| cos(\theta) - r)}{(-2 r |x| cos(\theta) + r^2 + |x|^2)^\frac{3}{2}} \hat{r} -\frac{r |x| sin(\theta)}{(-2 r |x| cos(\theta) + r^2 + |x|^2)^\frac{3}{2}} \hat{\theta} $ but I got stuck. It's similar to the espression I have to get but how?
EDIT I have tried to use the fact for example that $cos\theta=\frac{y_3}{r}$ where $r=|y|$ but nothing  I get $(0,0,\frac{|x|}{D})-\frac{1}{D}(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ where $D=|x-y|^3$ it is quite the right solution but it isn't

Why not write it in coordinate form and just calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$?

@zkutch I know it is simpler but I wanted to learn how to do such horrible calculations and where is my error

$
\def\R#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\l{\lambda}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q} \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\p{\partial}   \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\rr#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\RLR#1{\rr{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$Let $w$ be the vector difference between the points
and let $\l$ denote the length of $w$
$$\eqalign{
w &= \LR{y-x} &\qiq  {dw = dy} \\
\l^2 &= w^Tw &\qiq \l\,d\l=w^Tdw=w^Tdy  \\
}$$
Rewrite the function in terms of $\l$ and calculate its gradient
$$\eqalign{
f &= \l^{-1} \\
df
 &= -\l^{-2}d\l \\
 &= -\l^{-3}\LR{\l\,d\l} \\
 &= -\l^{-3}\;w^Tdy \\
\grad fy &= -\l^{-3}w \;\;\equiv\;\; \frac{x-y\;}{\frob{x-y}^3} \\
}$$
